# How can I smoothly animate a Material UI LinearProgress over a fixed time period?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to animate over 60 seconds and here's what I have so far:

```
export default function TimeLoader({ timeout }: ITimeLoaderProps) {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(1);

  useInterval(() => {
    setProgress(p => Math.min(p * 1.1, 100));
  }, 100);
  console.log({ progress });


  return (
    <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress} />
  );
}
```

But obviously this isn't done over 60 seconds. It finishes rather quick. If I increase the timeout time from 100 to something else, then it's a bit jerky.

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below uses CSS rather than JS to animate the progress bar over 60 seconds. It accomplishes this by using the `indeterminate` variant, but then customizing its CSS. The `indeterminate` variant leverages two bars in its animation. This example suppresses the second bar and changes the first bar to animate over 60 seconds once instead of [2.1 seconds infinitely repeating](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.1/packages/material-ui/src/LinearProgress/LinearProgress.js#L89). This example also changes the keyframes part of the animation so that it ends with a full bar, rather than ending with [the bar disappearing](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.1/packages/material-ui/src/LinearProgress/LinearProgress.js#L124). Using `forwards` in the animation causes the final state to stick when the animation finishes.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import LinearProgress from "@material-ui/core/LinearProgress";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  bar1Indeterminate: {
    width: "auto",
    animation: "$indeterminate1 60s linear forwards"
  },
  bar2Indeterminate: {
    display: "none"
  },
  "@keyframes indeterminate1": {
    "0%": {
      left: "-35%",
      right: "100%"
    },
    "100%": {
      left: "0%",
      right: "0%"
    }
  }
});

export default function LinearDeterminate() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <LinearProgress
        classes={{
          bar1Indeterminate: classes.bar1Indeterminate,
          bar2Indeterminate: classes.bar2Indeterminate
        }}
        variant="indeterminate"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit 60 second progress]

Relevant documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

---

Here's an equivalent example using v5 of Material-UI leveraging `styled` and Emotion's `keyframes`:

```
import React from "react";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import LinearProgress from "@material-ui/core/LinearProgress";
import { keyframes } from "@emotion/react";

const indeterminate1Keyframes = keyframes({
  "0%": {
    left: "-35%",
    right: "100%"
  },
  "100%": {
    left: "0%",
    right: "0%"
  }
});

const StyledLinearProgress = styled(LinearProgress)({
  "& .MuiLinearProgress-bar1Indeterminate": {
    width: "auto",
    animation: `${indeterminate1Keyframes} 60s linear forwards`
  },
  "& .MuiLinearProgress-bar2Indeterminate": {
    display: "none"
  }
});

export default function LinearDeterminate() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <StyledLinearProgress variant="indeterminate" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit 60 second progress]