# How to change the animation speed of a Material-UI Linear Progress Bar indeterminate?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm using a LinearProgressBar with the indeterminate variant in a React app to give a feedback that an action is ongoing.

I find that the animation is too fast, is there a way to reduce its speed?

Comment: Assuming this is for the [indeterminate variant](https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#linear-indeterminate)?

Comment: yes, ill clarify my post

Answer (score 4):

There is no prop provided in the LinearProgress component to adjust the animation speed so you're going to have to [play with class overrides](https://material-ui.com/api/linear-progress/#css) to override the [default styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.3/packages/material-ui/src/LinearProgress/LinearProgress.js#L103). In this case I'd increase the `animation-duration` to slow it down:

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import LinearProgress from "@material-ui/core/LinearProgress";

const SlowLinearProgress = withStyles({
  bar: {
    // apply a new animation-duration to the `.bar` class
    animationDuration: "8s"
  }
})(LinearProgress);

export default SlowLinearProgress;
```

[image: Edit slow LinearProgress]

---

For v5 of Material-UI, you can use `styled` instead of `withStyles`:

```
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import LinearProgress from "@material-ui/core/LinearProgress";

const SlowLinearProgress = styled(LinearProgress)({
  "& .MuiLinearProgress-bar": {
    // apply a new animation-duration to the `.bar` class
    animationDuration: "8s"
  }
});

export default SlowLinearProgress;
```

[image: Edit slow LinearProgress]

Related answer: [How can I smoothly animate a Material UI LinearProgress over a fixed time period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379238/how-can-i-smoothly-animate-a-material-ui-linearprogress-over-a-fixed-time-period/68381489#68381489)

Comment: When the first bar reaches the end, the "tail" seems to slow down a lot. This isn't exactly a slowed version of the behavior of a mui indeterminate linear progress bar

Comment: I'm not sure it doesn't fit the definition of "slow" - be default I believe it's around 1.25 seconds, I used 8 to just show an example. How is what you expected different?

Comment: Try with a greater duration (it's clearly visible with 16s). The start of the bar is always at the same speed. The tail starts very fast, then slows down to the speed of the start. The effect isn't proportional, only a part of the animation is slowed down compared to a vanilla indeterminate linear progress.

Comment: For people like me, who were brought to this post by google but where actually searching for how to change the **CircularProgress** animation speed: Use the `.MuiCircularProgress-circle` class instead.